# I am trying to use @DataProvider to run @test with Different Parameters, but getting exception

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

i want to pass parameter to @test to run multiple times with different data. so i am using @DataProvider which is retuning two dimensional Object array. i am having one dimensional  string so at first i am converting it to two dimensional array followed by assigning value to objects.  .  but getting following exceptions.

```
public class DtaProvider {

    public static String patchfileName = null;
    public static String[] patchsplit = null;
    public static String temp= null;
    public int number   = 0;

      @DataProvider(name = "getData")
      public Object[][] createData() {

          patchfileName = "hi,how,are,you";
          patchsplit = patchfileName.split(",");

          Object[] arr = patchsplit ;

          System.out.println(arr.length);

          for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
              System.out.println(arr[i].toString());
          }
          Object[][] data = new Object[arr.length][arr.length];

          for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
              data[x][x] = arr[x];

            }

          return data;

      } 



        @Test(dataProvider="getData")

        public void DownloadPatch(String patchfileNamea ){

            try{

            System.out.println("Name is b"+patchfileNamea);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                org.testng.Assert.fail("Failed to Download Patch to NgDriver " + e.getMessage());

            } 
        }
}


TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\Mohan Raj S\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1472908796\testng-customsuite.xml

4
hi
how
are
you
FAILED: DownloadPatch
org.testng.TestNGException: 
The data provider is trying to pass 4 parameters but the method testclasses.DtaProvider#DownloadPatch takes 1
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.injectParameters(Invoker.java:1257)
```

kindly help me how to pass parameter sequentially to my @test Method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned in error log that @Test method is taking only one parameter while @DataProvider is returning four parameters.

It is pretty simple that the number of parameters @DataProvider returns same should be passed in @Test method. Your @Test method should look like:

```
@Test(dataProvider="getData")
public void DownloadPatch(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4){
   System.out.println(param1);
}
```

**Update:1**

Even if you have some reason to pass only one param in your @Test method then you need to modify your @DataProvider in this way.

```
public Object[][] createData() {
    patchfileName = "hi,how,are,you";
    patchsplit = patchfileName.split(",");
    Object[][] data = new Object[patchsplit.length][1];
    for (int x = 0; x < patchsplit.length; x++) {
        data[x][0] = patchsplit[x];

    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Priyan, my  method should accept only one parameter, can you guide me how to modify my two dimensional object array? so that parameters will be sequentially returnd

Answer (score 1):

If you know the parameters that you want to pass, then the following can be used to pass a single parameter to your `@Test` method.

```
@DataProvider(name = "getData")
public Object[][] createData() {
    return new Object[][] { { "hi" }, { "how" }, { "are" }, { "you" } };
}
```